# How can I unmount a drive every time I reboot?

Tags: automount

As relates to an answer to a previous [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/how-can-i-disable-the-2nd-hard-drive-in-my-27-imac), I'd like to unmount a built-in hard drive every time I boot up. (Or alternately arrange for it not to be mounted). How do I do this?

Comment: I edited my answer to your other question to include a way that you can prevent the drive from being mounted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The following Hint on Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060930150059172) details a way to do this. Basically you'll create (or modify) the file `/etc/fstab` and add a line similar to:

```
UUID=F0E430C1-5558-3BB3-9FA9-6904B663FEEA  none  hfs  rw,noauto
```

The actual UUID will vary, you can find the UUID for your disk in `system.log`:

> In Mac OS X Panther, Disk Utility and the diskutil command doesn't display the UUID value. But if you look in the system.log file, when the disk is mounted, you can see something similar to this (line breaks added for narrower display):
>
> ```
>  … localhost diskarbitrationd[87]: disk1s9   hfs  
>    77F3E84D-E0ED-3194-96A5-BED10893FFF4  FireWire HD    
>    /Volumes/FireWire HD
>  … localhost diskarbitrationd[87]: disk1s10  hfs  
>    F0E430C1-5558-3BB3-9FA9-6904B663FEEA  Mac OS X Disc 
>    /Volumes/Mac OS X Disc
> ```
>
> The string before the volume name is the UUID for the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Use a LaunchAgent (see [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/)) that runs at boot to unmount. If it runs too quickly, add a wait/pause/sleep. The action that unmounts can be in whatever you preferred scripting/automation language is (bash (hdiutil), Automator, AppleScript, etc.)