# How to allow an internal disk to sleep on 10.13

Tags: macos, hard-drive, diskutil

I have an internal disk which is noisy and seldom used. With previous versions of OSX I was able to spin it down by using `diskutil eject`, but with the latest High Sierra 10.13.4, after a few seconds it powers up again.

I am looking for a way to stop it powering up again or totally disabling it without physically opening the Mac.

Is this possible with software?

Note 1: Disk is not even mounted, I have it disabled in /etc/fstab. No matter which the sleeping time is, the disk never spins down. It only does afer running diskutils eject, but in few seconds it restarts. In previous versions of OS X it didnt happen, it switched off correctly.

Note 2: In the previous OS version (El capitan), I have it normally mounted, and unmounting it from the Finder was enough, it switched off correctly. This does not work now either.

Note 3: I tried disabling (kill -SIGSTOP) the processes "diskarbitrationd" and "diskmanagementd" just after disk ejection but result is the same, disk respwans after some seconds.

How to know which process is accessing the unmounted unit?

Comment: I’m curious what your sleep time is and if unmounting it helps? If so we can help you script that to run periodically or once at log in - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/

Comment: Disk is not even mounted, I have it disabled in /etc/fstab. No matter which the sleeping time is, the disk never spins down. It only does afer running diskutils eject, but in few seconds it restarts. In previous versions of OS X it didnt happen, it switched off correctly.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, in the previous OS version (El capitan), I have it normally mounted, and unmounting it from the Finder was enough, it switched off correctly. This does not work now either.

Comment: Be sure to edit those details in to the main post - people often skip the comments entirely or they get hidden / cleared periodically for various reasons

Comment: What specific Mac are you using and what drive connection technology is being used internally. I assume some flavour of SATA.

Comment: Yes, SATA. iMAC  from late 2009.

Comment: If the disk was mounted (perhaps worth doing for troubleshooting?), then `lsof` might help to find the process that is accessing it.